# data offline sync when app is in terminated state also

Tags: android, ios, nativescript

I need to sync the offline data to server and get new data even when the app is in a terminated state. I tried background fetch it works only when the app is in the background and suspended state. Does background fetch work in foreground in Swift? Does background fetch work in foreground in Android?

```
let MyHeadlessTask = async (event) => {
  console.log("this is headlessstask")
}
```

Comment: ignore the above code but need the solution

Comment: You will need a service.  Look into how to keep a service running in the background after your app closes.

Comment: You can use either Android Sync Adapter or Android JetPack Component - WorkManager to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

We call it background fetch for a reason, it's designated to run while app is in background, at least on iOS. With Android, it may be possible to run a service even while your app is in foreground.

Write your sync logics as a common class / method, invoke it from background fetch / service while app is in background. When app is in foreground, may be in application launch / resume events, you could again call that common class / method that which will do the sync.

Comment: Thanks Manoj' it helps a lot